# Disable screen saver on OS X 10.9

Tags: macos, screensaver

When I set my screen saver "start after" value, it resets within a few hours. I have not yet determined what event causes it to reset, but it does not require rebooting to occur.

Apple customer support had me delete the `com.apple.screensaver.plist` file from `/Library/Preferences/`, but that did not resolve the problem.

Since the start after value won't stay put, is there another way to disable the screen saver altogether?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Deleting that wouldn't work. The only keys stored in that property list, by default, are:

```
njboot$ defaults read com.apple.screensaver
{
    askForPassword = 1;
    askForPasswordDelay = 900;
}
```

These keys are tied to: `System Preferences > Security & Privacy > General > "Require Password 15 minutes (900/60) after sleep or screen saver begins."`

You need to modify current host properties (saved in the "By Host" folder). To do so, open **Terminal**, and enter the following command at the command line prompt:

```
defaults -currentHost write com.apple.screensaver idleTime 0
```

Here's the result:

```
defaults -currentHost read com.apple.screensaver`

{
    CleanExit = YES;
    PrefsVersion = 100;
    idleTime = 0;
    moduleDict =     {
        displayName = "Computer Name";
        moduleName = "Computer Name";
        path = "/System/Library/Frameworks/ScreenSaver.framework/Resources/Computer Name.saver";
        type = 0;
    };
}
```

0 = never. Log out and log back in for changes to take effect. Once you log back in, you will notice under `System Preferences > Desktop & Screen Saver > Start After: Never` is set. *This will override setting it via System Preferences. You can test this by setting the screensaver time, logging out, and logging back in. It will still read never.* If you wish to undo this command in the future:

```
defaults -currentHost delete com.apple.screensaver idleTime
```

[Googling the issue](http://osxdaily.com/2009/12/21/screensaver-not-working-in-mac-os-x-fix-screensaverengine-app-launch-problems/) revealed that a corrupted launch services database could be one possible cause, and rebuilding it may solve the underlying issue.